# jQuery equivalent of PHP's strtr

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What is the jQuery equivalent of PHP's strtr.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

I would prefer the simplest possible, pure jQuery solution.

JS would also be a great alternative.

Comment: [How about standard JS](http://phpjs.org/functions/strstr:551)

Comment: `jQuery: A fast, concise, library that simplifies how to traverse HTML documents, handle events, perform animations, and add AJAX.` It is not a string manipulation library, not a programming language and not a magic wand.

Comment: use plain js:`function strtr(str, tokens) {
  for (const i in tokens) {
    str = str.split(i).join(tokens[i]);
  }
  return str;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the [php.js implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtr:556).